# How to commit Fragment transactions in FragmentPagerAdapter in onLoadFinish callback method?

Tags: android, adapter, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I would like to notify `ViewPagerAdapter` that dataset changed in `Loader.onLoadFinish` callback function.

It is prevented because state of fragments might be saved.

From [LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished(Loader loader, D data)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html#onLoadFinished) method documentation:

> Note that normally an application is not allowed to commit fragment transactions while in this call, since it can happen after an activity's state is saved.`

How can I overcome this problem? How can I check in which state `Activity` is and commit `Fragment` transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've come with following solution:

Method `changeCursorInOtherThread` is used in `onLoadFinished` and `onLoaderReset`.

`Handler` is created in `Activity`:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mSaved = true;

}

private void changeCursorInOtherThread(final Cursor data) {
    if(!mSaved){
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mViewPagerAdapter.changeCursor(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Wanted to show a `DialogFragment` after `onLoadFinished()`. As you said it's not possible to commit fragment transaction inside `onLoadFinished()`. But then I realized, that I could just implement `LoaderCallbacks` in the `DialogFragment`. And it works like a charm. Instead of listening for the `Loader` to finish its job within an `Activity`, I do it inside the `Fragment`.

You could do the same. Instead of implementing `onLoadFinished()` inside your activity you could just implement it inside Fragments which are placed in your `ViewPager`. Of course in some cases it doesn't make sense in a `ViewPager`, it depends on your data structure.

There's more discussion on this issue [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/dXZZjhRjkMk).